# How to solve reportviewer from VS2010 to VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

I 've searched the answer and trial for half day. I am using VS2015 and MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 that the project was develop in VS2010.

however, the error appears,

> ASP.NET runtime error: The base class includes the field
>   'ReportViewer1', but its type
>   (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer) is not compatible with the
>   type of control (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer). please modify  the associated registration that is causing ambiguity and pick a new tag prefix

I cannot find reportViewer.Webfor.dll v12.0.0.0. I've done  the following steps/procedures , ReportViewer is still invalid: 
Thanks for helping!!

1. install reportViewer 2015 runtime, Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package
2. install SQL server data tool 2015
3. in .aspx,

   ```
   <%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, 
   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" 
   Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
   ```
4. in web.config,

   ```
   <handlers>   
       <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode"
       verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
       type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler,
       Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
       PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/> 
   </handlers>
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve my problem.
you have to delete all old version V10 and add new version v12 of 4 reportviewer.dll. 
the path is C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common 
second, we need to copy those 4 .dll and paste into bin folder in your project.
Then you can perfectly run your reportviewer

Comment: You should be able to include references from your project to report viewer via NuGet too.